# Mock контекста при юнит тестировании

Tags: c#, asp.net, юнит-тесты, .net-framework

Проект ASP под .Net Framework
Есть класс теста, тестирует методы HomeController : BaseController

HomeController использует поле _siteSecurityContext, а объявлено оно в BaseController
Где и как оно инжектируется - не знаю, проект для меня новый и большой - навскидку в поиске по коду не нашёл

Что мне нужно: чтобы в момент вызова тестируемого метода из класса теста поле _siteSecurityContext был проинициализировано, но к этому моменту
оно null. Пробовал "мокать" его по-разному с помощью фреймворка Moq - не помогает

```
class MethodXXXTest
{
    private readonly _c;
    MethodXXXTest()
    {
         _c = HomeController(_xService, _yService...... ещё 8 заинжектенных 
          сервисов)
    }

     public void CheckXXXTest()
     {
          ///
          ///
          ///
          _c.CheckXXX(/// - тестируемый метод
     }   
}


public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController()
    {
       // заинжектенные сервисы
    }
    public void CheckXXXTest()
    {   // должно быть не null, сейчас null
        _siteSecurityContext.Foo(... 
    }
}


public abstract class BaseController : Controller, ...
{
    // тут он объявлен
    protected SiteSecurityContext _siteSecurityContext {get; set;} - 
    инжектится непонятно где. его надо за мокать из класса теста
}
```

Comment: `Что мне делать?` Показато минималь минимальный воспроизводимый пример кода.

Comment: не могу из-за безопасности

Comment: Так напишите код-куклу, который повторит нужную часть иерархии классов, где вы так же не сможете замокать нужный класс. То есть код, воспроизводящий проблему, а не ваш оригинальный код. Кстати, может так получиться, что пока вы его пишете - сами разберетесь с проблемой.

Comment: Какого типа поле `_siteSecurityContext`? Это базовый тип Asp.net, или класс/интерфейс, описанный в проекте? Присваивается ли это поле где-нибудь в конструкторе?

Comment: Ищите в коде все места, где присваивается значение _siteSecurityContext, и расставляйте брекпойнты. Если не найдете - вставляйте в тестируемом коде debug-only callback, и подменяйте обращение к полю на заинжекченное значение. Если не знаете как - напишите, приведу пример.

Comment: добавил код - заглушку

Comment: @PashaPash, на время отладки можно поле превратить в свойство и поставить брейкпоинт в сеттер

Comment: `_siteSecurityContext` такое название говорит всем опытным, что это должно быть поле, и это подтверждается даже комментариями выше, но оказывается это свойство! В студии есть поиск всех ссылок на нужный член класса, поэтому найти то место, не представляет никакой проблемы. Именуйте свойства с заглавной буквы, а приватные поля с нижнего подчеркивания, это уже давно и повсеместно является стандартом.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант, если найти место инжекта слишком тяжело, или если не хочется дергать дополнительную логику - паттерн Public Morozov под флагом Conditional:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public HomeController()
        {
            // заинжектенные сервисы
        }

        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        public void Debug_SetSecurityContext(SiteSecurityContext context)
        {
            _siteSecurityContext = context;
        }

        public void CheckXXXTest()
        {   // должно быть не null, сейчас null
            _siteSecurityContext.Foo();
    }
    }


    public abstract class BaseController
    {
        // тут он объявлен
        protected SiteSecurityContext _siteSecurityContext { get; set; }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Arrange
            var controller = new HomeController();
            var context = new SiteSecurityContext();

            controller.Debug_SetSecurityContext(context);

            // Act
            controller.CheckXXXTest();

            // Assert
            // TODO: проверить результаты вызова
        }
    }
}
```